# Можно ли разделить код GUI и обработчика событий в разные файлы? (Python, PyQt5)

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Пытаюсь отделить код интерфейса приложения и обработчиков событий для читабельности и удобства.

Проблема в том, что обработчики событий оперируют элементами *GUI* и при запуске программы выдается ошибка о том, что элемент используемый в обработчике не определен, но он определен в модуле *GUI*.

**GUI_modul.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtSql
import sys
from modul1 import input_cliced

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

###########################################################
########            Стартовое окно             ############
###########################################################
start_window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
start_window.setWindowTitle('База приборов')

button_input = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Внести новый прибор')
button_input.clicked.connect(input_cliced)


start_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
start_layout.addWidget(button_input)
start_window.setLayout(start_layout)

###########################################################
######## Окно ввода информации о новом приборе ############
###########################################################
input_window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
input_window.setWindowTitle('Ввод нового прибора')
input_window.resize(QtCore.QSize(1000,300))
###Поля ввода информации в окне ввода
input_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

input_place_devprod = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
input_place_devmode = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
input_place_devSN = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

input_submit_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Input')

###Добавление полей ввода в слой окна ввода данных
input_layout.addWidget(lable_devprod)
input_layout.addWidget(input_place_devprod)
input_layout.addWidget(input_place_devmode)
input_layout.addWidget(input_place_devSN)
input_layout.addWidget(input_submit_btn)
###Передача слоя в окно ввода данных
input_window.setLayout(input_layout)


start_window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Отрывок кода **modul1.py** с обработчиком событий

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

def input_cliced ():
   input_window.show()
```

`start_window` запускается, но при нажатии на `button_input` вылетает ошибка о том, что `input_window` не определен, но он определен в первом модуле.

Вопрос - как сделать чтобы модули видели объекты друг друга? (Среда Visual Studio)

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Изменил код до минимально воспроизводимого

Comment: То что вы предоставили, не очень похоже на минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Пожалуйста всегда предоставляйте [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вы задумали, может выглядеть примерно так:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtSql
from modul1 import InputWindow

 
class StartWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('База приборов')

        button_input = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Внести новый прибор')
        button_input.clicked.connect(self.input_cliced)   
        
        self.label_devprod = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_devmode = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_devSN = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        start_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        start_layout.addWidget(self.label_devprod)
        start_layout.addWidget(self.label_devmode)
        start_layout.addWidget(self.label_devSN)
        start_layout.addWidget(button_input)        
        
        self.input_window = InputWindow(self)
        
    def input_cliced(self):
        self.input_window.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = StartWindow()
    w.resize(QtCore.QSize(640, 480))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**modul1.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class InputWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setWindowTitle('Ввод нового прибора')
        self.resize(QtCore.QSize(1000,300)) 
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        self.input_place_devprod = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.input_place_devmode = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.input_place_devSN = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        input_submit_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Input')
        input_submit_btn.clicked.connect(self.goStartWindow)
        
        input_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        input_layout.addWidget(self.input_place_devprod)
        input_layout.addWidget(self.input_place_devmode)
        input_layout.addWidget(self.input_place_devSN)
        input_layout.addWidget(input_submit_btn)
        
    def goStartWindow(self):
        self.parent.label_devprod.setText(self.input_place_devprod.text())
        self.parent.label_devmode.setText(self.input_place_devmode.text())
        self.parent.label_devSN.setText(self.input_place_devSN.text())
        self.hide()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @user440171 что не так?

Comment: Все так. огромная благодарность!